# Как исправить ошибку Property 'placeholder' does not exist on type 'FormTypes'?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

подскажите пожалуйста, как решить ошибку **Property 'placeholder' does not exist on type 'FormTypes'. Property 'placeholder' does not exist on type 'RadioType'.**
Вот мой код:

```
type InputType = {
  value: string;
  name: string;
  placeholder: string
}

type RadioType = {
  value: string;
  name: string;
}
type FormTypes = InputType | RadioType;


<Input
  value={inputValue}
  name={name}
  placeholder={placeholder}
/>
<Radio
  value={value}
  name={name}
/>
```